# Multiple mediation: significant but small ab(s)

Tags: mediation

I ran a multiple mediation analysis for my poster (3 mediators). The total effect, direct effect, and all the indirect effects are significant. However, the indirect effects are very small (~0.0040, 0.0022, & 0.0020). The sample size for this data set is around 12,000 people. Does that mean I essentially have no mediation going on? Are my results essentially meaningless? I was thinking of submitting this idea to a conference but now I am not so sure.